# Image styles: Does not work with large images

Tags: media

The image styles, thumbnails and so on, are not created on my Drupal 7 site, when the original file is bigger than 5 MB. I did not find any error message in the log messages and the v-server, the site is hosted on, seems to have sufficient power to convert large files: I have 4 GHZ CPU and 4 GB RAM. 
The original file is uploaded correctly and I have double checked the file permissions.

Does anybody know, what to do?

Comment: did you look in php.ini for your maximum allowed memory usage, or execution timeout? If a fileupload widget works ok Apache should be able to run imagestyles ... personally I hate GD, did you try imagemagick?

Comment: Maximum allowed memory usage is 256 MB, should be enough for images of 7, 8 MB or something. The max_execution_time is set to 80 sec. That seems to be all right. I saw that the imagemagick module is still an alpha version, is it reliable?

Comment: 7 or 8 meg images?!?! i hope your uploading "web safe" jpgs and gifs and not like BMP. I would try imagemagick instead of GD for larger images like that. I used D6 imagemagick with no problems. Get -dev version as it has a 2012 release, and not a 2011 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Imagemagick and now everything works as expected.