# ImageStyles does not create thumbnail image while uploading large images

Tags: 7, files, media

I try to create a website using Drupal on a shared host, everything goes fine except ImageStyles.

When I try to upload large images (more than 1MB) thumbnails does not created , but works fine with smaller one.

I searched it and found these two:

[Failing to create thumbnail, medium and large images](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19152/drupal-7-fails-to-create-thumbnail-medium-and-large-images-what-am-i-doing-wro)

[Image styles: Does not work with large images](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56484/image-styles-does-not-work-with-large-images)

but I can't use these solutions because I'm using a shared host.

Any suggestion will be appreciatived ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Drupal can't resize images due to not enough RAM or due to timeouts, and you can't change RAM and timeout settings, and can't change library, then you have only three options:

1. Limit image size to something your installation can handle.
2. Provide additional field for thumbnails and make your users prepare them.
3. Change hosting.

Personally I would go with 3.

Comment: how can I get the real problem is which one: Ram or Timeouts? I want to talk to host provider and ask him/her to fix it

Comment: Well, that's something only **he** can see, it's in the server's error log. Unless he provided you with error log access, of course. But if he would, you wouldn't be asking now.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the **image upload size** using field settings in the admin to less than 1 MB and show a help text that max upload size is 1 MB.

Other option already given by Molot.

Hope it will  help you.

Comment: Actually, this option was also already given by me, in point 1, but without details you provided... I believed hostings so restricted are song of the past anyway, and restricting images to something with poor quality sounds a bad idea. Way better than errors and missing thumbnails, of course, but bad anyway.

Comment: @Molot, I have already given priority to your answers.